# String manipulation to remove tokens from string and assign the result to a variable?

Tags: php, string

Given the string variable in $widget_text...

```
$widget_text = '[widget_and-some-text]';
```

I need to do a string manipulation to end up with...

```
$widget_text_sanitized = 'and-some-text';
```

How?

ie, I thought this should work:

```
$widget_text = trim($widget_text,'[]');
$widget_text_sanitized = str_replace('widget_','',$widget_text);
```

Comment: So is it always `widget_` which has to be removed?

Comment: Yes. I'm using 'widget_' as the token stamp, then the "and-some-text" becomes the id used to assign the widget to a sidebar

Comment: What about  `<?php list($widget, $widget_text_sanitized) = explode("_", $widget_text); echo $widget_text_sanitized;?>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a regular expression, you could have something like this :

```
$widget_text = '[widget_and-some-text]';

if (preg_match('/\[widget_([^\]]+)\]/', $widget_text, $matches)) {
    var_dump($matches[1]);
}
```

Which would get you :

```
string 'and-some-text' (length=13)
```

Comment: This is the way to go +1. No bulky strpos + substr magic, but a consice regex.

Comment: Please not that using a regex is not the fasest solution. It might be an overkill to use it in this case, as the text that has to be removed is always the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
$widget_text_sanitised = substr($widget_text, 8, -1);
```

This will remove the first 8 and the last character from the string (no matter what characters they are).